# mapDispatchToProps doesn't add actions to component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm tryng to use connect like in Redux docs ([here](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#connect)) and I'm also using `redux toolkit` to work with `redux` ([link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/quick-start))

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { actions } from '../../redux/actions';

import FormComponent from './Form';

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    item: 'state.item'
})

const mapDispatchToProps = { actions }

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(FormComponent)
```

In my FormComponent I'm getting `item` props from `mapStateToProps` but `actions` are not passed down

My actions look like this

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const registerUser = createAction<Object, 'REGISTER_USER'>('REGISTER_USER');

export const actions = {
    registerUser
}
```

And if I do `console.log(actions)` it is an object with function.

All the help will be appreciated.

Comment: Given your comment and referencing the docs, the issue would appear to be how you are creating the object you pass, try this: `mapDispatchToProps = actions`, or simply pass `actions` in directly `connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(FormComponent)`

Comment: @James : your deleted answer is basically correct.  The original code in the question is almost definitely nesting the action creators one level too many, which will actually result in _no_ action creators being passed as props.  Passing the `actions` variable (which I assume is already an object) as the second arg to `connect` should fix the problem.

Comment: @markerikson yeah, I think really it was just my second part that was wrong (and just a bit of an oversight on my part). I've used Redux for many years and ashamed to say I wasn't aware of the automatic dispatch call when an object is supplied (was this introduced later or has this always been the case?). I'll re-instate the answer and remove the second part.

Comment: Yes, the "object shorthand" form has existed since before React-Redux 1.0 was published :)  See [React-Redux issue #1 (heading: "Case with More Control")](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1) for the earliest mention.  We have this documented in [the React-Redux usage guide on `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), and [the Redux Style Guide recommends using the object shorthand](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-object-shorthand-form-of-mapdispatch-with-connect).

Comment: @markerikson haha classic case of "if it ain't broke, done fix it" in my case. Will definitely be using this moving forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
mapDispatchToProps = { actions }
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
 mapDispatchToProps = {
   actions: {
     registerUser
   }
 }
```

As per the [docs](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators/) `bindActionCreators` expects an object hash of action creators. In this example, you have nested yours under an `actions` property which (based on the [source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9c0b74192348fd10b66b44f39bf659d4125164f2/src/bindActionCreators.js#L45-L47)) will result in them being excluded from the returned props.

If you want the actions to be accessible directly from props then you can set `mapDispatchToProps = actions`, or just pass `actions` directly into `connect` e.g.

```
 connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(FormComponent)
```

Comment: But in the docs mapDispatchToProps  used as an object. I event says that ```We recommend using this “object shorthand” form.``` (link https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#connecting-the-components)

Comment: @Allan oh, you are right, apologies, it's been a while since I've read the docs on Redux tbh. I'll remove this then as it no longer seems relevant

Comment: Nitpicking: passing an object as the `mapDispatch` arg passes the object straight to [`bindActionCreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators).  That function only looks at the first level of values in the object, and does not deeply recurse. So, there would be _no_ dispatch-related props being passed into this component with `connect(mapState, {actions})(MyComponent)`, because the `actions` object isn't a function and would be ignored.

Comment: @markerikson I'm suggesting `connect(mapState, actions)(MyComponent)` which would be the equivalent to `connect(mapState, { registerUser })(Component)`. Are you maybe confusing the use of `{ actions }` in the OPs code to my answer?

Comment: Sort of.  I'm saying that `connect(mapState,actions)(Component)` is the correct answer overall, but that in the first half of your answer, `props.actions.registerUser()` will _not_ be available, because `mapDispatch` doesn't deeply recurse over objects.

Comment: @markerikson got you, but just to be super pedantic....`props.actions.registerUser` would still be available though? Just not dispatchible?

Comment: No, that's what I'm saying.  `props.actions` _would not exist at all_, because `bindActionCreators` would see that `mapDispatchObj.actions` is an object and not a function.  Therefore, it would be ignored.  You can see that behavior in [the `bindActionCreators` source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9c0b74192348fd10b66b44f39bf659d4125164f2/src/bindActionCreators.js#L45-L47).

Comment: @markerikson ah ok, yeah the code is clear. I'll update my answer just to clarify what we've discussed.